# jQuery easyui load link in same opened tab (from where it was clicked)

Tags: jquery, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

Sorry for asking this, i'm quite a newbie on jquery but, i just couln't make it work.
I'm having an application using jeasyui using a tree on the left, built from a json file.

When the user clicks on the nodes of the tree based on the URL param from json, a new tab is opened.So far so good.
The tabs are containing some links, and my problem is that when that link is clicked, it is allways loaded in a new window. 
What i want to achieve is to open the links from the page loaded in the tab, in the same opened tab, from where it was clicked.

For adding the tabs dynamically from the tree i'm using the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function(){   
 $('#tree_menu').tree({    
    animate:true,    
    <!--checking what it was clicked form tree--!>
     onClick: function open1(node){
            <!--if exists, select it--!>
                    if ($('#tabs').tabs('exists',node.text)){
                        $('#tabs').tabs('select', node.text);
                    <!--if not open it--!>
                    } else {
                            $('#tabs').tabs('add',{
                                title: node.text,
                                    closable:true, 
                                    href:node.url,
                                tools:[{  
                            iconCls:'icon-mini-refresh',  
                            handler:function(){  
                            alert('refresh');  
                    }  
                    }]

                    });
                    }
        }
    });     
}); 
</script>
```

This the html code:

```
    <div data-options="region:'west',split:true" title="Main Menu" style="width:250px;">
        <div class="easyui-accordion" data-options="fit:true,border:false">



            <div title="Tree:" style="padding-top:10px;">
                    <ul id="tree_menu" class="easyui-tree" data-options="url:'../layout/tree_data1.json',animate:true,dnd:true"></ul>
            </div>

            <div title="Tips&Tricks" style="padding:10px">
                Tips&Tricks
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-options="region:'center'"> 
        <div id="tabs" class="easyui-tabs" data-options="fit:true,border:false,plain:true" style="padding-top:5px">
            <div title="About" data-options="href:'../layout/_content.html'" iconCls="icon-ok" closable="true" style="padding:10px"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I could find a way, embedding an iframe in the tab, but is not what i want, because i want to use the embeded functions/methods of the tab, and also the nice preloader wich the easyui has.

Please, can someone help me with some code that works?
It's been more than 2 days, since i'm trying without success. :(

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did u try this?

```
$('#example').tabs({
load: function(event, ui) {
$('a', ui.panel).live('click', function() {
    $(ui.panel).load(this.href);
    return false;
});
}
});
```

Comment: `code`<script type="text/javascript"> 
       $(function(){   
           $('#tree_menu').tree({    
           animate:true,    
           onClick: function open1(node){
 if ($('#tabs').tabs('exists',node.text)){  $('#tabs').tabs('select', node.text);   } else {
 $('#tabs').tabs('add',{     title: node.text,     href: node.text,      closable:true,             iconCls:'icon-reload'      });
}
}
});     
}); 


$('#tabs').tabs({
load: function(event, ui) {
$('a', ui.panel).live('click', function() {
    $(ui.panel).load(this.href);
    return false;
});
}
});
`code`

Comment: Do onething. Just try this with a static tab. ie put a link to the content of the tab that you already have(not the dynamically added one) and check this works.

Comment: Tried this also, using the first tab which is added manually:
`code`   <div data-options="region:'center',title:'Welcome!',iconCls:'icon-edit'">
   <div id="tabs" class="easyui-tabs" data-options="fit:true,border:false,plain:true" style="padding-top:5px">
    <div title="- INFO page -" data-options="href:'../layout/_content.html'" iconCls="icon-tip" style="padding:10px"></div>
  </div>`code`
In _content.html there is a link to another page, and using the javascript above, it is still loading the link in a new window. 
What would be the issue?

Comment: Does the click event get fired when u click on the link? also, the link opens only in new window or both?

Comment: the link is opening only in new window. For the click event i don't know how to check if is fired or not. :(

Comment: A good example of what i want to acheive is this one: http://www.jeasyui.com/documentation/index.php

Comment: Any ideas? I've tried all the ways found here (as seen it was treated in similar posts) but without success.

Comment: Can someone help me please with this?

Comment: Is there any way of achieving this?